# Instantiate browser-like WebSocket in QML JS

Tags: javascript, qt, websocket, qml, faye

I have a Qt/QML application that I'd like to use to connect to a [Faye](https://faye.jcoglan.com/) server. Faye's JS client code fails within Qt because of this code:

```
var WS = global.MozWebSocket || global.WebSocket;

module.exports = {
  create: function(url, protocols, options) {
    if (typeof WS !== 'function') return null;
    return new WS(url);
  }
};
```

...which fails in QML because there is no global `WebSocket` available by default.

QML has a [`WebSocket` component](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocket.html) that I can instantiate, but this does not make it available in JavaScript.

How can I use the QML WebSocket to push a JS object into the global space so that when I `import "qrc:/faye-client.js" as Faye` the code there sees a global `WebSocket` object available?

---

**Edit**: while I believe that a protocol-compatible shim should be possible, allowing QML to use code written for web browser WebSockets, I ended up writing [my own Faye client wrapped around a QML WebSocket](https://github.com/Phrogz/rb3jay/blob/master/qt-client/BayeuxClient.qml).

Comment: You can instance a `WebSocket` object in `JS` with either `Qt.createQmlObject` or `Qt.createComponent`. I would define js file as a singleton so it will be accessible everywhere. But anyway, I think that `WebSocket` from HTML5 is not same as `WebSocket` in QML.

Comment: @folibis What really matters is the underlying WebSocket protocol, that is a RFC implemented  both sides. So, actually, one could say that they are the same.

Comment: Yes, the protocol itself I guess the same as the html one. But as I see at the API's level it's completely different. You can just compare [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocket.html) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).